# How to add user to group after signup in Django

Tags: django, macos, authentication, mezzanine

I'm trying to automatically add users to groups on signup in a django/mezzanine project. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, it works fine locally with dev server, but not with live production server, which is a mac running OS X 10.8. There are no virtualenvs and I have been editing the views.py located at

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/accounts/
```

Here's the view:

```
def signup(request, template="accounts/account_signup.html"):
    """
    Signup form.
    """
    profile_form = get_profile_form()
    form = profile_form(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        if not new_user.is_active:
            if settings.ACCOUNTS_APPROVAL_REQUIRED:
                send_approve_mail(request, new_user)
                info(request, _("Thanks for signing up! You'll receive "
                                "an email when your account is activated."))
            else:
                send_verification_mail(request, new_user, "signup_verify")
                info(request, _("A verification email has been sent with "
                                "a link for activating your account."))
            return redirect(next_url(request) or "/")
        else:
            info(request, _("Successfully signed up"))
            auth_login(request, new_user)
            g = Group.objects.get(name='01_registriert') 
            g.user_set.add(request.user)
            user.save()
            return login_redirect(request)
    context = {"form": form, "title": _("Sign up")}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Am I editing the wrong file? Any help is very welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where the `user` variable was defined, this may throw an error and is not necessary for add the user to a group, another way to add a user to a group is:

```
   user_obj.groups.add(group_obj)
```